# Summarise Pivot table in multiple ways at once

Tags: excel, pivot-table, standard-deviation

I have a Pivot table in excel, the data in the table isn't important to my question. With a pivot table I am able to summarise the data in different ways. Is it possible to summarise the data in multiple ways? I would like to summarise it in the average as well as the standard deviation.

I cant seem to be able to select multiple ways to summarise the data at once.

Comment: You can add the same value field(s) more than once, and choose different aggregation functions for them, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Well, when you create a pivot table it generates a row Called grand total, is it possible in some way to display the Standard deviation at the same time as the grand total?

Comment: Only by repeating the field as I mentioned.